# retrieve information from a url

Tags: java, wrapper, data-mining, information-retrieval

I want to make a program that will retrieve some information a url.
For example i give the url below, from
[librarything](http://www.librarything.com/work/9767358/78536487)

How can i retrieve all the words below the "TAGS" tab, like

> Black Library fantasy Thanquol & Boneripper Thanquol and Bone Ripper Warhammer ?

I am thinking of using java, and design a data mining wrapper, but i am not sure how to start. Can anyone give me some advice?

EDIT: 
You gave me excellent help, but I want to ask something else.
For every tag we can see how many times each tag has been used, when we press the "number" button. How can I retrieve that number also?

Comment: I'd recommend using Python or Perl if you're going to prase HTML. I've had good experiences with Python when I made a program similar to your example, can't really share anything at the moment though. There is a library specifically made for [parsing HTML in Python](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html), you can also check out [regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) and [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html).

Comment: @Griffin: that seems to be a DOM based parser wihch would only result in ugly and boilerplate code. Also, using regex to parse HTML is plain [insane](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: @BalusC I haven't used the HTML parser myself, I was redirected to that library on the Python channel on Freenode after using regex. There seems to be different opinions regarding that, some people say it's okay and some people say it's not okay. Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org). It allows you to select HTML elements of interest using simple [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

E.g.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.librarything.com/work/9767358/78536487").get();
Elements tags = document.select(".tags .tag a");

for (Element tag : tags) {
    System.out.println(tag.text());
}
```

which prints

```
Black Library
fantasy
Thanquol & Boneripper
Thanquol and Bone Ripper
Warhammer
```

Please note that you should read website's `robots.txt` -if any- and read the website's terms of service -if any- or your server might be IP-banned sooner or later.

Comment: I recommend http://www.selectorgadget.com/ as a CSS selector and it generate a valid xPath

Comment: this is just a tool to get the CSS from the html to use it in the Element.select(String selector) function.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before using PHP with a page scrape, then parsing the HTML as a string using Regular Expressions.

[Example here](http://www.oooff.com/php-scripts/basic-php-scraped-data-parsing/basic-php-data-parsing.php)

I imagine there's something similar in java and other languages.  The concept would be similar:

1. Load page data.
2. Parse the data, (i.e. with a regex, or via the DOM model and using some CSS selectors or some XPath selectors.
3. Do what you want with the data :)

It's worth remembering that some people might not appreciate you data mining their site and profiting / redistrubuting it on a large scale.