# Return some information from a website in java

Tags: java, web

How can I open a website and return some information from it in Java ? For example I want to go to http://xyz.com, enter my family name and return my national code

Comment: Always search first before posting. There are a number of similar threads that may answer your question, or at least help you refine it , such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822420/retrieve-information-from-a-url or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359439/how-do-i-retrieve-a-url-from-a-web-site-using-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.net.HttpURLConnection` to connect to a website. For scraping information from the loaded website you can use a Java HTML Parser library (for example [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)) to be able to traverse through the DOM and/or retrieve relevant pieces of information from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

With [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), that is a tool for testing web applications, you can do all that you say. Try to check its documentation

This is an example case [example in java](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#java)

Answer (score 0):

If that site returns information in XML format, then its possible to do XML parsing to get the result you desire.

SAX is really handy in XML parsing in these cases.